# Load balancing between two ip addresses and port?

Tags: load-balancing

If there are two Linux boxes running the same application on the same port, are there any services (AWS, Google, anything else) available out of the box which can help to build Load Balancer?

[image]

Comment: Look up _reverse proxy_ servers like nginx, caddy, haproxy etc.

Comment: Thanks @abdusc, these are reverse proxies, are there any out of the box services on top of this?

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/